NLP: Алгоритм инвертирования синтаксического дерева
Существует ли алгоритм для получения последовательности shift'ов и reduce'ов из готового синтаксического дерева?

Эээ… это собственно синтаксический анализ. Shift и reduce происходят при синтаксическом разборе, а готовое синтаксическое дерево — это результат разбора. Через какие именно шаги проходит разбор — зависит от грамматики (очевидно, одно и то же синтаксическое дерево может быть результатом разбора по бесконечному числу различных грамматик).

Возможно я недостаточно ясно изложил. Мне как раз и нужно инвертировать процесс синтаксического анализа. Не на основе последовательности сдвигов-переносов сформировать граф синтаксического дерева, а наоборот – имея готовый граф на его основе получить последовательность сдвигов-переносов. У меня есть собственные наработки, просто хочу узнать, возможно уже существует более изящное решение и не нужно изобретать велосипед.

Ну например, если ваша грамматика содержит правило expr: '(' expr ')', то исходные тексты 1 и (((1))) произведут одинаковые деревья. Но разбор второго выражения содержит несколько шифтов, а первого нет.

Хм, кажется наврал, скобки всё же попадут в результирующее дерево.

Нет, стоп. Всё-таки я был прав. Детали разбора наподобие скобок у нас находятся в Parse Tree. А в AST они не попадают, и вытащить оттуда их невозможно. (Разница тут.) Поэтому AST для 1 и (((1))) одинаковые.

Вы говорите о работе синтаксического анализатора компилятора, если я правильно понял) Я в этом не силен, мой вопрос больше касается обработки естественной речи

Хм, ну shift/reduce + syntax tree для меня звучало как работа компилятора. Сорри :)
